# what is the relation between class MyHomePage and runApp Function

Tags: flutter, dart

in default flutter project runApp function  it countain  the MyApp class as aparameter so when we run app It's normal for the content of the class MyApp and content of StatelessWidget class  to appear , but how the run app function  get  content of others classes like MyHomepage class and StatefullWidget class.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 

void main() => runApp(MyApp()); 


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 

 @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return MaterialApp( title: 'Flutter Demo', 
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue, ), 

home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'), ); }} 

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget { MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key); 

final String title; 

@override 

_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();} 

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> { 

int _counter = 0; 

void _incrementCounter() { 
setState(() { 


_counter++; }); } 

@override

 Widget build(BuildContext context) { 


 return Scaffold( appBar: AppBar(


 title: Text(widget.title), ), body: Center(

 

mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[ 

Text( 'You have pushed the button this many times:', ), Text( '$_counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1, ), ], ), ),

 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( onPressed: _incrementCounter, tooltip: 'Increment', child: Icon(Icons.add);}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter is based on a widget tree. To the `runApp` method only the root of the tree is passed. In this example, `MyApp` is the root of this tree and all other widgets are referenced only by being in `MyApp` or its children. For example, here `MyHomePage` is a child of `MyApp`. Away from the pages, the "smaller" widgets like `Text` or `Container` are also part of this tree and referenced in the single pages.

Do you have a more specific question about what you don't understand or have I already answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever valid widget you pass inside *runApp()* will be displayed and it will be considered as the root widget of the app tree.

So, it is best to use a widget which returns a *MaterialApp()* widget as this will constitute the window frame of your app on which other widgets will be displayed as pages.

These page widgets that will be routed to the MaterialApp widget should in turn return a *Scaffold()* widget.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer yesterday and it is that the relationship between the runApp function and MyHomePage class is that parameter named home in MyApp class takes MyHomePage class as its value